# .htaccess remove a part of the url in PHPthumb

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, zend-framework

I did the research and couldnt find anything useful

I have a problem with phpthumb ,

```
http://localhost/sandbox/public/PhpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd&w=140px&h=120px&q=100
```

I need to replace the the ../ proceeding the src. Basically to remove all ../ occrunces. Or to redirect to an error page. I prefer both.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)phpThumb\.php?(src)?(=)?(\.\.\/)*$ images/unknown.gif [NC]
```

I suspect that the above rule which i created is not correct. Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this: `RewriteRule ^(.+phpThumb\.php)\?src=(\.\./)+[^&]+(.*)$ $1?src=images/unknown.gif$3 [NC]` it will replace src=value if ../ is in the value, the problem is that src should be the first get parameter in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this kind of modification via mod_rewrite like this. It is only concerned with the actual URL, not with GET parameters. You should handle those from within the executed PHP script.

Other option would be to add a `RewriteCond` using `%{QUERY_STRING}` which is (in comparison to `RewriteRule`) able to work with GET parameters. Then you can use `%1`, `%2`, ... in the replacement part of your `RewriteRule` instead of `$1`, `$2`, ...

Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\./
RewriteRule phpThumb\.php$ images/unknown.gif [L]
```

Comment: Sure you can look at [this](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/rewrite/1/) example

Comment: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/ This is a great tut as well. Btw your answer helped. Thanks.